# Move woocommerce shop page image to left

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, genesis-theme-framework

I'm setting up a shop using Genesis and Woocommerce. I have the columns set to one and I added the short description beneath the image and before the button using the woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.

Ideally I'd like the image to take up 50% width with the description taking the other 50% and then the button beneath both taking up 100%.

Just wondering if this is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes. it is possible you can modify the templates files add some classes and use flex or grid to arrange it way you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Or, another option to what Latheesh advised would be that you could make both the image and description `display: inline-block;` & have a `margin: 2%;` with a `width: 46%;` and then for the button have it a `width: 100%;` and a `clear: both;`

All done in css.